# pandas read_csv displays quotation marks on the first and last item of every row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My .csv file looks like this:

```
"col1","col2"
"1","text1"
"2","This a "TEXT". However, I cannot parse it."
```

I.e. it contains commas and quotation marks within a value.
Using `sep` parameter in `read_csv()` function gives quotation marks in the beginning and ending on each line:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep = '","', engine = 'python')
df


    "col1   col2"
0   "1      text1"
1   "2      This a "TEXT". However, I cannot parse it."
```

What can I do to read my file correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on your interesting idea, you can also add the first and last quotes as separators, then drop the unwanted columns:

```
data = io.StringIO('''"col1","col2"
"1","text1"
"2","This a "TEXT". However, I cannot parse it."
''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=r'","|^"|"$', engine='python').iloc[:, 1:-1]
```

Output:

```
   col1                                        col2
0     1                                       text1
1     2  This a "TEXT". However, I cannot parse it.
```

The advantage is that you directly get the correct types (if needed):

```
df.dtypes

col1     int64
col2    object
dtype: object
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/if0YUn/1)